# How to get value from array, which is inside objects in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get values from an array,

which is inside of objects:

```
const post = {
    sticky: false,
    template: "",
    format: "standard",
    _embedded: {
        author: [{
            0: {
                id: 2,
                name: "Charlie"
            }
        }],
        term: ""
    }
}
```

I need to get value of author.name, how should I map through this?

I tried this in my return:

```
return(
    <div className={className}>
        <h2>
            {post._embedded.author[0].name}
        </h2>
    </div>
)
```

But it's not working, I get an error `Cannot read property 'author' of undefine`.

Sorry for silly question, but it's hard for me to understand.

Comment: It's an array so you need to pass an index to get the object in it. Like `author[0].name`.

Comment: put some effort in before asking others to do your work for you. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung sorry, but I can't even suggest how to do it, I googled but couldn't find an answer. I know how to map if it was array initially.

Comment: @AtinSingh you mean something like this: post._embedded.author[0].name?

Comment: @Aslan yes. That doesn't work?

Comment: @AtinSingh No, I edited my question and added your example, can you look at it? maybe I'm doing smth wrong. There is an error, Cannot read property 'author' of undefine.

Comment: Where is this post object coming from? state? are you setting state somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
post._embedded.author[0]['0'].name
```

You can try it out using the below snippet.

```js
const post = {
    sticky: false,
    template: "",
    format: "standard",
    _embedded: {
        author: [{
            0: {
                id: 2,
                name: "Charlie"
            }
        }],
        term: ""
    }
};

const name = post._embedded.author[0]['0'].name;

console.log(name)
```

So the jsx would be

```
return(
    <div className={className}>
        <h2>
            {post._embedded.author[0]['0'].name}
        </h2>
    </div>
)
```